# How can I access downloads/data folder in Android device?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am building an Android app in which I have to upload files to http server. For example docs in my download/data folder. How can I access. Do I need to set up permissions in manifest?

I did this :

```
private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;
String selectedPath = "";
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("file/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

I am doing this in my second activity and I added this activity to the manifest. I received these errors.

```
10-16 06:00:30.065: E/AndroidRuntime(546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 06:00:30.065: E/AndroidRuntime(546): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=file/* }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need the permissions INTERNET, and READ_PHONE_STATE.

As for the pulling of documents into your phone you would need to issue a GET or a POST via http.

Below is a tutorial on HTTP in Android.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html